# Doze mode Vs MQTT Connectionlost

Tags: mqtt, android-doze

When Android device enters in to Doze mode,connectionlost Callback is triggered in MQTT

**What I have tried till now?**

1.Written broadcast receiver to detect app is entering in to Doze mode or not.

2.Once It enters,Doing Partial WAKE LOCK.

**My Questions here is?**

Is there any way to make my app always connected to internet to make sure that my app user won't miss any notifications.

Comment: do you have found a solution?